# How to sift through the tag name for image from the pasted elements

Tags: vba, web-scraping

So far, while writing code in VBE to make a parser I have used the "img" tag and the "src" attribute to scrape an image but I stumbled trying to go through the portion I'm pasting below. Can't filter the portion I need to use in my code to parse an Image.

```
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("card card-lg")
For i = 0 To topics.Length - 1
Set topic = topics(i)
    Cells(x, 1).Value = topic.getElementsByClassName("wine-card__image-wrapper")(0).getElementsByTagName("img")(0).src
    x = x + 1
Next i
```

And a sample of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="wine-card__image-wrapper">
<a href="/wineries/tschida/wines/angerhof-eiswein-gruner-veltliner-2012">
<figure class="wine-card__image" style="background-image: url(//images.vivino.com/thumbs/qlER3oggQVKh1FZn7YGxZg_375x500.jpg)">
<div class="image-inner"></div>
</figure>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: Thanks sir Nathan for your kind reply. Here is the code I've written so far. Please look above.

Comment: You can access the "style" parameter I believe, so (not very tidy, but didn't want to post full answer) `.getElementsByClassName("wine-card__image-wrapper")(0).Children(0).Children(0).style.backgroundimage`

Comment: Bam!!!!! Working like magic. Sir Nathan, you just made my day. You are awesome. Very grateful to you.

Comment: How can I accept your answer?. Can't find any button or something.

Comment: My pleasure  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the "style" attribute I believe, so

```
Sub t()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim d As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim dv As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement
Dim ha As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MswWSiRW2RgZqyZW26Ulq5SXRsbaGAKA_Cdk%3D"

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

Set d = ie.document
Set e = d.getElementsByClassName("wine-card__image-wrapper")(0)
Set ha = e.Children(0).Children(0)
Debug.Print ha.Style.backgroundImage

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, sir Nathan could you please give me a hint how to get the working code to parse image from this chunk: [<img alt="" class="" src="https://images.craigslist.org/00l0l_hW1X6OeifVZ_300x300.jpg">]

Comment: `INSTR` `MID` or `split(split(s,"src=")(0),">")(0)` not test the last.